Wrangling Factors in Tibble
  my_tibble <- tibble(
  Name = factor(c("Yellow", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Purple")),
  Anomaly = factor(c("No", "YES", "NO", "YES", "NO")))

In my tibble, how can I filter to keep observations that keep only the unique Names so that the final product looks like:
my_tibble2 <- tibble(
  Name = factor(c("Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Purple")),
  Anomaly = factor(c("No", "YES", "YES", "NO")))



Try my_tibble |> dplyr::distinct(Name, .keep_all = TRUE). See Unique on a dataframe with only selected columns for more options.
